# Get pip/setuptools version of package from within the package?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a package using `setuptools` for it's deployment. I want to have a function within the package (CLI tool) which reports the version of the package. This should report the `version` field used in the call to `setup`. Is there a way I can access this value on the installed package?

For example, my `setup.py` calls `setup` with `version = '0.1.6'` and also installes a command line tool `tool`. I want that a call to `tool --version` prints the version `0.1.6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often common practice to list this in your package's main `__init__.py` file. For instance, if you package was called `sample`, and lived in the `sample` directory, you would have a `sample/__init__.py` file with something like this:

```
__version__ = '0.1.6'

def version():
    return __version__
```

And make use of that however you want in your CLI interface.

In your `setup.py`, if you wish you can read this value from your code in order not to create redundancy, something like this:

```
import os.path

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Read the version number from a source file.
# Why read it, and not import?
# see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/pypa-dev/0PkjVpcxTzQ/discussion
def find_version(*file_paths):
    # Open in Latin-1 so that we avoid encoding errors.
    # Use codecs.open for Python 2 compatibility
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(here, *file_paths), 'r', 'latin1') as f:
        version_file = f.read()

    # The version line must have the form
    # __version__ = 'ver'
    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",
                              version_file, re.M)
    if version_match:
        return version_match.group(1)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")

setup(
    name="sample",
    version=find_version('sample', '__init__.py'),
    # ... etc
```

For lots more discussion on different ways to implementing this sort of goal, please check http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#version

Comment: If I have to go this approach would not simply storing the version in a `version.txt` file be a lot easier than the regex approach?

Comment: This one allows the version number to be accessed both programmatically by your python application, and statically / textually by the install script (setup.py). The actual `find_version` function you could make a lot simpler if you wished, this is a full version with maximum comptability for python 2 & 3 and and also reporting an error.